# Construction of three tangent circles in a triangle

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle I want to construct three tangent circles inscribed in the triangle (every two sides of the triangle are tangent lines of one of the circles). For better understanding of the problem I tried to draw desired result (picture is only approximative, I do not know exact construction). Could you give me some hint, how exact construction can be done?

[image]

Comment: The circle tangent to $A B$ and $A C$ lies on the line bisecting angle $B A C$. From there I'd write equations for the circles, and look for the conditions that make the two intersection points between the circles centered at $S_1$ and $S_2$ coincide.

Comment: Are you looking for a construction using straightedge and compass?

Comment: This is a special case of a circle packing, so I know how a solution can be computed using a variational principle. But that won't be of much use for a construction with straightedge and compass.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a construction using straightedge and compass. However if direct construction is not possible I am also interested in some computational solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seemed to me that since there are many different [centers in a triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center), one of them might be useful for your construction. Going through the links of various centers, I stumbled upon a name for the problem you describe: these three circles are known as **[Malfatti circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles)**.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles) has some details on a [construction by Steiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles#Steiner.27s_construction). [ℝⁿ](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/856/) was kind enough to add a comment below, providing links to details about some of the steps in that construction, namely the construction of [bitangents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles#Tangent_lines_to_two_circles) and [incircles to quadrilaterals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral#Characterizations). The latter seems obvious in hindsight…

Comment: Certainly you can [construct bitangents using a straightedge and compass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles#Tangent_lines_to_two_circles), and [the incircle to a tangential quadrilateral is centered on the point of concurrency of its angle bisectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral#Characterizations).

Answer (score 4):

I put a detail steps to show how to construct circles by straight and compass. the principle is provided by MvG.

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed that $A_2A_3 = B_2B_3 = C_2C_3 = s+r-IA-IB-IC$, where $s$ is the half-perimeter and $r$ the inradius of the triangle?  This shortens the construction.