# A problem relating to Circumscribed Quadrilaterals and Triangles.

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle ABC. For an arbitrary interior point X of the triangle denote by A<sub>1</sub>(X) the point intersection of the lines AX and BC, denote by B<sub>1</sub>(X) the point intersection of the lines BX and CA, and denote by C<sub>1</sub>(X) the point intersection of the lines CX and AB.

Determine all points P in the interior of the triangle for which each of the quadrilaterals AC<sub>1</sub>(P)PB<sub>1</sub>(P), BA<sub>1</sub>(P)PC<sub>1</sub>(P) and CB<sub>1</sub>(P)PA<sub>1</sub>(P) has an inscribed circle.

[image: This is what the figure looks like]

What I have been able to prove includes-

i)  B<sub>3</sub>A<sub>1P</sub> = A<sub>4</sub>B<sub>1P</sub>, likewise for other corresponding pairs

ii) AB<sub>1P</sub>-AC<sub>1P</sub> = PB<sub>1P</sub>-PC<sub>1P</sub>=B<sub>2</sub>C<sub>1</sub>=DA<sub>1P</sub> , likewise for other corresponding pairs

iii)    AC<sub>1P</sub>+BA<sub>1P</sub>+CB<sub>1P</sub> = s       (semi perimeter of ∆ABC)

I know that this point must be the [Inner Soddy Center](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoddyCenters.html) of ∆ABC but am finding it difficult to prove it.

Please help..

Comment: Looks a bit like [Malfatti circles](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/295950/35416). Not sure whether that reference is of any use.

Comment: This isn't really like Malfatti Circles..
The figure looks similar but actually these circles are completely different - they are not tangent to each other..

Answer (score 1):

Finally cracked it!!

To show that point P is the inner soddy centre, we show that P lies on a hyperbola with focii $B,C$ and passing through $D$.

That means that we effectively have to show that
$$CP-BP=CD-BD$$

Notice that $CB_1=CB_3=$ Length of Tangent from $C$ to the circle $O_B$.

Hence,
$$\begin{align}CP+B_1P =CB_3 \\
\implies CP=CB_3-B_1P 
\end{align}$$
Similarly,$$BP=BC_4-PC_2$$
So,
$$\begin{align}
CP-BP
&=CB_3-BC_4+(PC_2-PB_1) &(1)\\
&=(CC_4+B_3C_4)-(BB_3+B_3C_4)+(PC_1-PB_2) &(2) \\
&=CC_4-BB_3+B_2C_1 &(3) \\
&=CA_{1P}-BD+DA_{1P} &(4) \\
&=CD-BD &(5)
\end{align}$$
Also, $$BP-AP=BF-AF$$
$$AP-CP=AE-CE$$

Therefore P lies on the intersection point of all three Hyperbolae that i mentioned earlier-***This must be a unique point***.

Now, the inner Soddy Centre satisfies these properties.  Thus, it is the required point P.

Comment: I edited your formatting a bit for clarity. Please double-check that I didn't change the nature of your equations.

Comment: I get a little lost at step $(4)$. It might help if I knew exactly how $D$, $E$, $F$ are defined. Are they the feet of perpendiculars from $P$? (The diagram makes them look *close*, but not quite.)

Comment: $D, E, F$ are defined to be the feet of the perpendicular from the incentre $I$(the small grey point near $P$) of the triangle.
Step $(4)$ follows from results that i was able to prove before i posted this question online.
(They are the ones that i have written below the Figure in the question.)

Comment: They can be derived by considering a general case wherein A triangle $ABC$ is divided into two triangles $ABX$ and $ACX$ by a line passing through $A$. Now, draw the incircles of triangles $ABX$ and $ACX$ and try proving that the length of the internal tangent of the circles is equal to $DX$ where $D$ is the foot of the perpendicular from the incircle upon $BC$.
I think i should add that to my answer.
:)